# Docker run gives Error: Cannot find module '/app/NPM'

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm-install, npx

I'm going through an introductory Docker course, and it's instructing me to create a docker file where I'm encountering the error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/NPM'
```

when I run the command:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 3ce0a937488d
```

The command to install the app on my local system is:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
```

This is Dockerfile.dev:

```
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["NPM", "RUN", "START"]
```

This is the build command:

```
docker build -f ./Dockerfile.dev .
```

The full error message from the running the image is this:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/app/NPM'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:763:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show what's there in the docker file ?

Comment: Can you explain the question? There's no running process. so I can't run <docker  exec -ti> to attach to it.

Comment: I had a very similar issue. Removing the entire node_modules folder and re-installing worked for me

Comment: Linux systems are generally case-sensitive, and the all-caps `NPM` doesn't look right (though it also wouldn't produce that error).  Does lowercase `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]` work better?

Comment: @DavidMaze you're exactly right. I somehow lost track of the fact those are just Linux commands and was looking at docker-related stuff.